# Why Docker PHP container works on Ubuntu host but not on Manjaro host

Tags: php, docker, php-fpm

I setup my new laptop with Manjaro Xfce and love it but I cannot get my primary dev project to run on the new host.

This project is used by more than 10 developers, 9 on Ubuntu and 1 on a Macbook. No issues for them but when I run it, everything works until the last minute when supervisord runs php-fpm and I see this error.

```
ERROR: Unable to globalize '/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/*.conf' (ret=2) from /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf at line 143.
ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf'
ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

it's not a folder issue, checked and double checked. exactly the same config and build as the other installs. I checked the docker versions and they are all good.

I tried to circumvent the problem and copy in a custom php-fpm.conf and comment out the last line in the file that includes the '/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/*.conf'

that gave me a new error.

```
WARNING: [pool www] child 331 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0"
WARNING: [pool www] child 331 said into stderr: "ERROR: Unable to open primary script: /app/html/home.php (Permission denied)"
```

I have double checked the permissions on my old setup running Elementry OS 5.1 (Ubuntu 18.04) and they are identical and look like this.

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.0  0.0   8256  2324 ?        Ss   10:55   0:00 make serve-dev_local
root         301  0.1  0.1  59592 20604 ?        S    10:55   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord -n --configuration /app/dock
root         304  0.2  0.3 165256 54776 ?        S    10:55   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
root         305  0.0  0.0  29664  2896 ?        S    10:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
root         306  0.0  0.0  34512  5912 ?        S    10:55   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data     307  0.4  0.6 537048 104572 ?       S    10:55   0:00 php /app/artisan queue:work long --queue=long --sleep=5 --tries=1
www-data     308  0.4  0.6 462524 101792 ?       S    10:55   0:00 php /app/artisan queue:work long --queue=long --sleep=5 --tries=1
root         309  0.0  0.0 680736 13500 ?        Sl   10:55   0:00 /usr/bin/newrelic-daemon -f
root         310  0.0  0.0 254324  2964 ?        Sl   10:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
www-data     311  0.0  0.0  34884  3400 ?        S    10:55   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data     312  0.0  0.0  34884  2532 ?        S    10:55   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data     313  0.0  0.0  34884  2532 ?        S    10:55   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data     314  0.0  0.0  34884  2532 ?        S    10:55   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data     331  0.0  0.2 165256 46296 ?        S    10:55   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data     332  0.0  0.2 165256 45572 ?        S    10:55   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data     333  0.0  0.2 165256 45572 ?        S    10:55   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data     334  0.0  0.2 165256 45572 ?        S    10:55   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
root         424  0.0  0.0  19868  3564 pts/0    Ss   10:57   0:00 bash
root         430  0.0  0.0  38304  3300 pts/0    R+   10:57   0:00 ps aux
```

I don't know what else to check. I have built a simple PHP docker container and it works just fine and also but a Laravel install with Lando.dev and it works as well.

If you can point me in the right direction would so greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you said is permissions looks like the output of `top`.

Comment: Hey Andrew, the permissions above are the output of  `ps aux` in the container to see the services are running with the usual users.

Answer (score 0):

We faced exactly the same problem with php-fpm, working on ubuntu and not on manjaro, and found the solution.
Our `docker-compose.yml` file was setup to run with `privileged: true`, which caused exactly this issue in php-fpm.
If you encounter that error, make sure you are runing the container not in privileged mode as there might be differences between the host systems.